# Let be $\pi : U(2) \to \mathbb{S^3}$ the fibre bundle, defined by $A = (a , b ) \mapsto b$. Does it have a section?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fiber-bundles

Let be $\pi : U(2) \to \mathbb{S^3}$ the fibre bundle, defined by $A = (a , b ) \mapsto b$, where $U(2)$ is the group of unitary $2 \times 2 $ matrices and $a,b \in \mathbb{C}^2$. ($b \in \mathbb{S}^3$ as $\mathbb{S}^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4 \cong \mathbb{C}^2$). Does it have a section? Is there a quick way to see that or have a intuition at least?

Comment: Please make the body of your question be self-contained. It has to make sense even if one removed the title.

Comment: What is $a,b\in (a,b) ?$

Comment: Moreover, in what way a pair (a,b) is an element of U(2)? On the other hand, even if it is a bundle it will probably not be a vector bundle (for the total space is compact!) so what exactly do you mean by non vanishing section?

Comment: I mean a map $i : \mathbb{S}^3 \to U(2) $, s.t. $pi \circ i = id_{\mathbb{S}^3}$ and $ i (b) \neq id $ for any $b \in $\mathbb{S^3}$.

Comment: hm I did misread something. for the result I want to use, I just need that is has a section. I edit it.

Comment: Yes, just assign to each $b\in C^2$, $\|b\|=1$, the unique $a$ such that $(a,b)\in SU(2)$ (that is, it has determinant $1$). This gives you a homeomorphism $S^3\simeq SU(2)\subseteq U(2)$, although I think it doesn't respect the group structure.

Comment: How do I see that there is such an $a$ such that $(a,b) \in SU (2)$ ? Do you have an idea where it fails to respect the group structure?

Comment: It's not clear what the map $\pi$ is: In general $b$ is not a unit vector (and usually $\Bbb S^3 \subset \Bbb C^2$ is the space of vectors of norm $1$ with respect to the usual Hermitian structure). For example, what is $\pi(\operatorname{id}_{\operatorname{U}(2)})$?

Comment: I think, it is as one has a unique form for unitary matrices as described in the wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_matrix . Then the $b$ has the form $(c, exp(-i \phi ) d^* $ and $|c|^2 + |exp(-i \phi) d^*|^2 = 1 $.

Comment: @peter, Why do you think there is a unique such a?

Comment: After all these comments, I still don't know what you are asking.

Comment: Try $S^3\ni b\mapsto (1,b)\in U(2)$. I'm afraid your question includes too little background to garner any respectable answer.